# Static django to link css file

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

`"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found 127.0.0.1:8000/static/core/css/index.css)"` Error.

I have an html file and a css file that run fine, but when I try to add the same html and css files to a django project and link them using static it no longer works.

However, I don't think the issue is with the static link (css file is stored at project_name/core/css/core/index.css):

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/css/index.css' %}">
```

Here is the entire html and css if the issue is not with the code above(the css is very long and I don't think the issue is within the css file, but you can see it working with no issue at https://jsfiddle.net/mfgqz0rj/):

index.html,

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    {% load static %}
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="author" content="colorlib.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,800" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/css/index.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="s006">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Search</legend>
          <div class="inner-form">
            <div class="input-field">
              <button class="btn-search" type="button">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
              <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="" value="Zip Code" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="suggestion-wrap">
            <span>New Arrivals</span>
            <span>Ladies</span>
            <span>Mens</span>
            <span>Accessories</span>
            <span>Sale</span>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

index.css:

```
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers (opinionated).
 */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 */
article,
aside,
footer,
header,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 * 1. Add the correct display in IE.
 */
figcaption,
figure,
main {
  /* 1 */
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Add the correct margin in IE 8.
 */
figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */
hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 1 */
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */
pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * 1. Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove gaps in links underline in iOS 8+ and Safari 8+.
 */
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57- and Firefox 39-.
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline;
  /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Prevent the duplicate application of `bolder` by the next rule in Safari 6.
 */
b,
strong {
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */
code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font style in Android 4.3-.
 */
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Add the correct background and color in IE 9-.
 */
mark {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 */
audio,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in iOS 4-7.
 */
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10-.
 */
img {
  border-style: none;
}

/**
 * Hide the overflow in IE.
 */
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers (opinionated).
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */
button,
input {
  /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */
button,
select {
  /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Prevent a WebKit bug where (2) destroys native `audio` and `video`
 *    controls in Android 4.
 * 2. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */
button,
html [type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */
button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */
button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */
fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */
legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  display: table;
  /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
  white-space: normal;
  /* 1 */
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 * 2. Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */
progress {
  display: inline-block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: baseline;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE.
 */
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10-.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10-.
 */
[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */
[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */
[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding and cancel buttons in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */
::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */
/*
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 * 1. Add the correct display in Edge, IE, and Firefox.
 */
details,
menu {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */
summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Scripting
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 9-.
 */
canvas {
  display: inline-block;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE.
 */
template {
  display: none;
}

/* Hidden
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10-.
 */
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-before: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  -webkit-padding-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-after: 0;
  border: 0;
}

legend {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  -webkit-padding-end: 0;
}

/*===============================
=            Choices            =
===============================*/
.choices {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.choices:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.choices:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.choices.is-disabled .choices__inner, .choices.is-disabled .choices__input {
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.choices.is-disabled .choices__item {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__inner {
  padding-bottom: 7.5px;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__button {
  background-image: url("../../icons/cross-inverse.svg");
  padding: 0;
  background-size: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10em;
  opacity: .5;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__button:hover, .choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__button:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #00BCD4;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"]:after {
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #333333 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 11.5px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2.5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"].is-open:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #333333 transparent;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"][dir="rtl"]:after {
  left: 11.5px;
  right: auto;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-one"][dir="rtl"] .choices__button {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-multiple"] .choices__inner, .choices[data-type*="text"] .choices__inner {
  cursor: text;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-multiple"] .choices__button, .choices[data-type*="text"] .choices__button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  border-left: 1px solid #008fa1;
  background-image: url("../../icons/cross.svg");
  background-size: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: .75;
}

.choices[data-type*="select-multiple"] .choices__button:hover, .choices[data-type*="select-multiple"] .choices__button:focus, .choices[data-type*="text"] .choices__button:hover, .choices[data-type*="text"] .choices__button:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.choices__inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 7.5px 7.5px 3.75px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-height: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.is-focused .choices__inner, .is-open .choices__inner {
  border-color: #b7b7b7;
}

.is-open .choices__inner {
  border-radius: 2.5px 2.5px 0 0;
}

.is-flipped.is-open .choices__inner {
  border-radius: 0 0 2.5px 2.5px;
}

.choices__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.choices__list--single {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 16px 4px 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

[dir="rtl"] .choices__list--single {
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.choices__list--single .choices__item {
  width: 100%;
}

.choices__list--multiple {
  display: inline;
}

.choices__list--multiple .choices__item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 3.75px;
  margin-bottom: 3.75px;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  border: 1px solid #00a5bb;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.choices__list--multiple .choices__item[data-deletable] {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

[dir="rtl"] .choices__list--multiple .choices__item {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 3.75px;
}

.choices__list--multiple .choices__item.is-highlighted {
  background-color: #00a5bb;
  border: 1px solid #008fa1;
}

.is-disabled .choices__list--multiple .choices__item {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  border: 1px solid #919191;
}

.choices__list--dropdown {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2.5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2.5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.choices__list--dropdown.is-active {
  display: block;
}

.is-open .choices__list--dropdown {
  border-color: #b7b7b7;
}

.is-flipped .choices__list--dropdown {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-radius: .25rem .25rem 0 0;
}

.choices__list--dropdown .choices__list {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  will-change: scroll-position;
}

.choices__list--dropdown .choices__item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

[dir="rtl"] .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable {
    padding-right: 100px;
  }
  .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable:after {
    content: attr(data-select-text);
    font-size: 12px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  [dir="rtl"] .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  [dir="rtl"] .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 10px;
  }
}

.choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable.is-highlighted {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable.is-highlighted:after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.choices__item {
  cursor: default;
}

.choices__item--selectable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.choices__item--disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  opacity: .5;
}

.choices__heading {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  color: gray;
}

.choices__button {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.choices__button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.choices__input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 2px;
}

.choices__input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .choices__input {
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.choices__placeholder {
  opacity: .5;
}

/*=====  End of Choices  ======*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.s006 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: #CD5C5C;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.s006 form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 790px;
}

.s006 form legend {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 59px;
}

.s006 form .inner-form {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 32px 10px 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #666;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field input.placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field input:hover, .s006 form .inner-form .input-field input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search {
  width: 70px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search svg {
  fill: #ccc;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all .2s ease-out, color .2s ease-out;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search:hover, .s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search:hover svg, .s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search:focus svg {
  fill: #666;
}

.s006 form .suggestion-wrap {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.s006 form .suggestion-wrap span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .s006 form .inner-form .input-field {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .s006 form .inner-form .input-field input {
    padding-left: 55px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .s006 form .inner-form .input-field .btn-search svg {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
  }
}
```

Comment: let's inspect and go to the network tab. Then reload the page, see is there any error?

Comment: 3 things pop up."127.0.0.1", "css?family=Poppins:400,800" and "index.css". But when I click on them they all say "200(OK)"

Comment: I did find "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/core/css/index.css)" @ShafikurRahmanShaon

Comment: You said css file is stored at app/core/css/core/index.css, but then the link tag says core/css/index.css?

Comment: sorry I will change that now my app is named "core" but I always see example paths use "app". My mistake.

Comment: That's not what I meant, is the CSS stored at core/css/core or core/css?

Comment: CSS is stored in static/core/css/ @Sheedo

Comment: How about index.html?

Comment: that is stored at templates/core/index.html @Sheedo , I have built django projects before with no issue linking the css, which is why I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you define **STATIC_URL** in your settings:

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
2. Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes in your link tag:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/css/index.css" %}">`